# Cannot detect bootable USB

Tags: macos, usb, bootable-disk

I have a problem with installing windows:

#### USB Details:

Before I created a (what I classify as) bootable disk properly, I have went through the USB being corrupted because of me killing the dd process when running: `sudo dd if=/path/to/windows.iso of=/dev/rdisk1`. I forgot the `bs=1m`, so I killed the process. I used Internet Recovery to reset my disk because normal Recovery HD showed the error "Could not open device". The USB is a 16GB Kingston DataTraveler 100 G3.

---

Internet recovery deleted my Recovery HD partition and rEFInd.

After resetting the USB with Internet recovery, I ran the dd command again. It did not detect as a Bootable USB in <kbd>Opt ⌥</kbd> menu, nor in rEFInd. I tried to boot "Legacy OS" which led me to a black screen saying "No bootable device found - Insert device and press any key". So I re-plugged my USB and tried pressing a key, without any success. How do I properly (and preferably manually) create a bootable USB that boots Windows on mac, or how do I make the USB I made detectable?

---

I am running Mac OS X Mavericks (10.9.5)

Comment: If you want to install Windows on the Boot Camp partition then create the USB installer using Boot Camp Assistant, not dd.

Comment: It would help, if you would post the model of your Mac. Not all Mac's can install Windows using a USB port. If you have an internal DVD drive, it is usually best to just burn a DVD and install that way.

Comment: @user3439894 I made a partition manually and formatted it as MS-DOS FAT. i don't know why rEFInd recognized it as BootCamp (Legacy OS). I will try with BootCamp instead of dd

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to plug it into a different USB port. That made it detectable and I could proceed. I set it up with Boot Camp (including the partition), and it reset into the windows setup