# Problems with Windows bootable USB

Tags: macos, bootcamp, windows

I am using the Boot Camp Assistant to make a bootable USB. However I get either a black screen, or a message saying **No bootable device found - Insert one and press any key**

My USB used to work for Linux and Windows previously, so it shouldn't be a hardware related issue.

I have tried the following:

- I repaired every disk I possibly could.
- I tried pluging it into a different port (that resolved a linux installation problem I had earlier)
- I tried using the dd command instead of using bootcamp like this: `sudo dd if=/path/to/windows.iso of=/dev/rdisk1 bs=1m`
- Booting the disk from Option menu (That causes the black screen)
- Using rEFInd to boot into **Legacy OS**. That causes the message.
- Using rEFInd to boot into the USB disk. That causes the black screen.

Later I will post `diskutil list` and other outputs on request.

---

[Cannot detect bootable USB](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/187696/cannot-detect-bootable-usb) was a previous problem I had that I fixed. In this problem, the USB got detected, but it showed a black screen. The steps I used to resolve the previous problem do not work here.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cannot detect bootable USB](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/187696/cannot-detect-bootable-usb)

Comment: @Buscar웃 That was my earlier question with different symptoms and problems. The solution was to plug it into a different port.

Comment: What model Mac? No all Mac models can boot Windows installer from a USB port. This can be true even if you can boot a Linux installer from a USB port.

Comment: @DavidAnderson Macbook pro mid 2012 (I think). However I booted the windows USB previously on the same mac so I don't think ot is the issue. My OS (10.9) is the version I am using

Comment: Unless the flash drive is bad, I am out of ideas. I assume you created a FAT formatted partition before booting from the Flash Drive. What I mean is I assume you are trying a BIOS/MBR install and you have confirmed you have a hybrid partitioned internal disk. You could install just using the iso file, but that is a lot of extra effort that you should not have to go through.